# Protecting vs Securing

Tags: terminology

I encountered a question "true or false, replication is NOT a way to protect data". I answered true since I felt that protecting data meant securing the network and preventing unauthorized access to the data, and simply replicating it would not "protect" it. I was told that I was wrong and that replication would fall under protection and not security. What is the difference between these 2 terms?

Comment: It's a trick question.  Replication is one of many strategies for protecting data.  It is certainly not the only way, and it only protects it in a very specific scenario (failure of one source of data out of two or more.)  But it's protection.

Answer (score 5):

Protecting data is part of information security. It falls directly under:

- confidentiality
- integrity
- availability

In your case, replication is probably more aimed at availability. In this particular case it would depend how people define secure and protection in terms of data. So in my opinion, if you get such a question, also include your understanding of what security is and protection is.